# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MEMORY

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I've got a slight issue with my app once I enable proguard. The error that im getting is this following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
   Process: com.my.package, PID: 8032
   io.b.c.d: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MEMORY
```

As the error only occurs when proguard is enabled I'm guessing its something to do with the proguard rules? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes you should probably look into the proguard rules of the repos of whichever Rx library you're using in your project.